# Avoiding Unnecessary Class Declarations

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm doing a ML project and decided to use classes to organize my code. Although, I'm not sure if my approach is optimal. I'll appreciate if you can share best practices, how you would approach similar challenge:

Lets concentrate on preprocessing module, where I created **Preprocessor** class.

This class has 3 methods for data manipulation, each taking a dataframe as input and adding a feature. Output of each method can be an input of another.

I also have 4th, **wrapper** method, that takes these 3 methods, chains them and creates final output:

```
def wrapper(self):
   output = self.method_1(self.df)
   output = self.method_2(output)
   output = self.method_3(output)
return output
```

When I want to use the class, I'm creating instance with **df** and just call **wrapper** function from it. Which feels unnatural and makes me think there is a better way of doing it.

```
import A_class
instance = A_class(df)
output = instance.wrapper()
```

Comment: The class feels somewhat artificial. You could just as easily define a set of regular functions. `output = func_3(func_2(func_1(ef)))`.

Comment: A good example to base your code off of is the classes and methods in scikit-learn. Each manipulation is its own class, and you can bundle them together with a [pipeline object](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are great if you need to keep track of/modify internal state of an object. But they're not magical things that keep your code organized just by existing. If all you have is a preprocessing pipeline that takes some data and runs it through methods in a straight line, regular functions will often be less cumbersome.

With the context you've given I'd probably do something like this:

`pipelines.py`

```
def preprocess_data_xyz(data):
    """
    Takes a dataframe of nature XYZ and returns it after 
    running it through the necessary preprocessing steps.
    """
    step_1 = func_1(data)
    step_2 = func_2(step_1)
    step_3 = func_3(step_2)
    return step_3

def func_1(data):
    """Does X to data."""
    pass

# etc ...
```

`analysis.py`

```
import pandas as pd
from pipelines import preprocess_data_xyz

data_xyz = pd.DataFrame( ... )
preprocessed_data_xyz = preprocess_data_xyz(data=data_xyz)
```

Choosing better variable and functions is also a major component of organizing your code - you should replace `func_1`, with a name that describes what it does to the data (something like `add_numerical_column`, `parse_datetime_column`, etc). Likewise for the `data_xyz` variable.